# How to create a list of date string in 'yyyymmdd' format with Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format

I want a list of date range in which each element is `'yyyymmdd'` format string, such as : `['20130226','20130227','20130228','20130301','20130302']` .

I can use pandas to do so:

```
>>> pandas.date_range('20130226','20130302')
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-02-26 00:00:00, ..., 2013-03-02 00:00:00]
Length: 5, Freq: D, Timezone: None
```

But it is DatetimeIndex and I need to do some extra format transform, so how to do that in a neat way ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Or using  list comprehension:

```
[d.strftime('%Y%m%d') for d in pandas.date_range('20130226','20130302')]
```

Answer (score 20):

Using `format`:

```
>>> r = pandas.date_range('20130226','20130302')
>>> r.format(formatter=lambda x: x.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
['20130226', '20130227', '20130228', '20130301', '20130302']
```

or using `map`:

```
>>> r.map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
array(['20130226', '20130227', '20130228', '20130301', '20130302'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip of using .format(formatter=lambda x: x.strftime('%Y%m%d'))

Answer (score 9):

Easy and clean: do it directly with pandas date_range and strftime like this:

```
pd.date_range(start='20130226',end='20130302',freq='D').strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Resulting:

```
Index(['20130226', '20130227', '20130228', '20130301', '20130302'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 4):

For Just a `daterange`, `pandas` would be an overkill when you actually again have to reformat the date using `datetime`. The following solution simply uses `datetime` to serve your purpose

```
import datetime
def date_range(start_dt, end_dt = None):
    start_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_dt, "%Y%m%d")
    if end_dt: end_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_dt, "%Y%m%d")
    while start_dt <= end_dt:
        yield start_dt.strftime("%Y%m%d")
        start_dt += datetime.timedelta(days=1)


[e for e in date_range('20130226','20130302')]
['20130226', '20130227', '20130228', '20130301', '20130302']
```

Comment: Helpful function. Thanks.

Comment: I love this solution. `pandas` should not be used just for this problem